# React component is not re-rendering on state change

Tags: reactjs

So I have a problem when updating the state on my component. this.state.authenticated is passed to Navigation to hide/show login/logout button. However once the user logs in the state change is not rerendering the nav. I have to manually refresh the page to see the navbar rerender and show the logout button.

here is the code

```
const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      authenticated: false,
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('app token:', token);
    if (token) {
      this.setState({ authenticated: true});
    } else {
      this.setState({authenticated: false});
    }
    console.log('app componet will mount:', this.state.authenticated);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navigation authenticated={this.state.authenticated}/>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Register} />
        <Route path='/feed' exact component={Feed} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/feed/:id'  component={SingleGroup} />
        <Route path='/mygroups'  component={MyGroups} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

code for login action

```
export const login = (username, password, history) => {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post(`${url}/user/login`, {username, password})
      .then((data) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'SIGNIN_USER',
          payload: data,
        })
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.data.token);
        history.push('/feed');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'SIGNIN_ERROR',
          payload: err,
        });
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Where is the token coming from ?

Comment: I am getting it from the local storage. It is set if the user auth is successful

Comment: where is the code of it ?

Comment: added to question

Comment: okay , good. now from where you are getting token? where is the code for getting token?

Comment: its at the top of the app component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State **authenticated** only set once when **componentWillMount**. Your **App** component not connect to redux store, So App not rerender when store data changed. And **state.authenticated** till **false** at this point.
All data should come from redux store (not component state).
To solve: 
 - connect **App** to redux store or connect **Navigation** to redux store.
 - in function **mapStateToProps**, get "**authenticated**" value and return it to component props;
 - render Navigation base on **this.props.authenticated** value.

[Redux Connect Tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md)